# How to display something in label when a particular item is selected from the droppeddown list?

Tags: asp.net

im new to coding with a little exp in visual basic. I want to display the properties on labels when i click the option in the droppeddown list. if i select audi, i want the year and price to be displayed for it. same with merc's year and price. this is the code im using.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #form1 {
            width: 538px;
            height: 290px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="height: 164px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    Car Model
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true"
          OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>Mercedes</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Audi</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    
    
    <hr />
    Year :
    <asp:label ID="label1" runat="server"></asp:label>
    <br />
    Price :
    <asp:label ID="label2" runat="server"></asp:label>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, good going.. now just handle selected item text in `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` event, if else may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just neeed to do coding in code behind part for Dropdown's selected index change event below is the code that will help you.

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text = "Mercedes" Then
            label1.Text = "2013"
            label2.Text = "2000000"
        ElseIf DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text = "Audi" Then
            label1.Text = "2014"
            label2.Text = "1800000"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Try this.

Comment: syntax error it says...
 Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
        {
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Mercedes")
            {
                label1.Text = "2013";
                label2.Text = "2000000";
            }
            else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Audi")
            {
                label1.Text = "2014";
                label2.Text = "1800000";
            }
        End If

        }

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set "Value" Property in ListItem to identify which item you selected i.e. audi or merc..